# Spark Dataset using case class

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

When we have to convert a Spark Dataframe to Dataset. We generally use case class.
It means we are converting a Row of un-Type to Type.
Example:

```
case class MyData (Name: String, Age: Int)
import spark.implicits._
val ds = df.as[MyData]
```

Let say I have one RDD & mapping with a case class then converting to dataframe. Why at the end dataframe showing Dataset[Row].

```
case class MyData(Name: String, Age: Int)    
object learning extends App{
    
      val spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("dataFrames")
        .config("spark.master", "local")
        .getOrCreate()
    
      val data = Seq(("A",100),("B",300),("C",400))
      val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
      val rddNew = rdd.map( x => MyData(x._1,x._2) )
      val newDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rddNew)
      newDataFrame.show()
    }
```

[image]

Why not this dataframe is showing as Dataset[MyData]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the return type of `spark.createDataFrame` is `DataFrame` which is equivalent to `Dataset[Row]`.

If you want the return type to be `Dataset[MyData]`, use `spark.createDataset`:

```
import spark.implicits._
val newDataset: Dataset[MyData] = spark.createDataset[MyData](rddNew)
```

Comment: It means it is converting a case class type to row, when we using a createDataFrame?

Comment: Yes. Going into the source code of the method, we see
`def createDataFrame[A <: Product : TypeTag](rdd: RDD[A]): DataFrame = withActive {
    val encoder = Encoders.product[A]
    Dataset.ofRows(self, ExternalRDD(rdd, self)(encoder))
  }`